# How can I forbid PHP to access other folders?

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I am using GoDaddy shared Linux hosting and I hosted multiple domains with the same machine. Last week, one of my WordPress sites was infected with malware. Then this worm code spread to my all domains instantly.

How can I forbid to access other domains (folders) from a domain (folder)? Perhaps I can put something in my `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only chance to do that on shared hosting is the [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) setting.

In each web root, create a `.htaccess` file containing the following:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/current/web/site
```

if this works, every `fopen()`, `include()` etc. access outside `/path/to/current/web/site` should fail with an error message.

It can be that your provider has disabled this possibility - if they have, it'll be silently ignored. It could also be that an `open_basedir` has already been set centrally for all your sites. That setting could be inherited, rendering any further settings moot. You'll have to try out.

Comment: Hi Pekka thank you for your advice but after this modification my site down with "Internal Server Error" i asked to support the problem... and their response:

"Dear Uchiha Itachi,

I apologize for the confusion. php_admin_value open_basedir is not executable on our shared hosting environment.... bla bla ..." 

Is there a any way to doing this ?

Comment: @Uchicha sorry, I think in that case this is impossible to achieve. You would have to talk to Godaddy about making those settings, order separate hosting packages, or move to an ISP that supports the flag (or other means of separation between domains).

Answer (score -1):

I'd contact the godaddy support and inquire about using htaccess to restrict access.

- http://www.yorku.ca/computng/students/webpages/central_web/htaccess.html